# Django Passing list of objects to template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I have trouble of passing my get_profiles in the same template as r'^compose/$' here. r'^users/$' is what I'm using as a model and it works. "compose" is a function in my views.py.

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template

from messages.views import *

from userprofile.views import get_profiles

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', redirect_to, {'url': 'inbox/'}),
    url(r'^inbox/$', inbox, name='messages_inbox'),
    url(r'^outbox/$', outbox, name='messages_outbox'),
    url(r'^compose/$', compose, name='messages_compose'),
    url(r'^users/$', direct_to_template, {'extra_context': { 'profiles': get_profiles }, 'template': 'messages/users.html' }),
)
```

```
userprofile/views.py
def get_profiles():
    return Profile.objects.order_by("user")
```

I tried this:

```
url(r'^compose/$', compose, direct_to_template, {'extra_context': { 'profiles': get_profiles },  'template': 'messages/compose.html' }),
```

But I get a function object is not iterable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, you need to actually call the function, but if you do that in urls.py it will only be evaluated once per process. You don't want to do that.

You don't show what `get_profiles` does, but I assume it's some sort of utility function. I tend to think that those belong in a separate file, `lib.py` or `utils.py`, rather than views.py. (That is, assuming it's not actually a view itself - if it is, then you'll need to rethink your whole approach).

However, what I think you actually need to do is to make a template tag instead. You can keep the logic in `get_profiles` if you like, then make a simple tag that calls that function. Then you don't need to mess about with passing data in `extra_context` - just add the tag to your template.

Comment: Edited the post. get_profiles simply returns my Profile objects. And I want to list these in the template aside with my compose message. Can you elaborate on making a template tag? I will search on this.

Comment: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-template-tags/ - see especially the part about setting a variable in the context. Note, it seems more complicated than it actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding brackets to the function call maybe?

```
'profiles': get_profiles()
```

Otherwise you are just passing a reference to the function object.

But the problem is this would only be evaluated once, when urls.py is called.

Why not make a view function to correspond with the url 'users/'?

Comment: get_profiles() gives also 'function' object is not iterable. What do you mean by making a view function to correspond with the url users? How? Can I write something in my "compose" that would yield my list of users in the compose.html. Ultimately it's a message composer and I would like the users to be visible when writing one.

Answer (score 0):

`get_profiles()`, with parentheses