# Django templatetag User objects included

Tags: django, django-templates

Hey I have been struggling with this one alot now. I am trying to pass my user objects to a template so that I can list them, or list usernames. Thanks to the help I've got from here so far I have this.

```
from django.template import Library, Node, Template, VariableDoesNotExist,      TemplateSyntaxError, \
                        Variable
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
from django.db import models

register = Library()

class GetAllUsers(Node):
    def __init__(self, varname):
        # Save the variable that we will assigning the users to
        self.varname = varname
    def render(self, context):
        # Save all the user objects to the variable and return the context to the  template
        context[self.varname] = User.objects.all()
        return ''

@register.tag(name="get_all_users") 
def get_all_users(parser, token):
    # First break up the arguments that have been passed to the template tag
    bits = token.contents.split()
    if len(bits) != 3:
        raise TemplateSyntaxError, "get_all_users tag takes exactly 2 arguments"
    if bits[1] != 'as':
        raise TemplateSyntaxError, "1st argument to get_all_users tag must be 'as'"
    return GetAllUsers(bits)

#register.tag('get_all_users', get_all_users)
```

When I use this code with

```
{% load getusers %} 
{% get_all_users as allusers %}
{% for user in allusers %}
     {{ user }}
{% endfor %}
```

In my template I get Caught TypeError while rendering: unhashable type: 'list'. And it is specifically {% get_all_users as allusers %} thats causing it. I tried {% for user in get_all_users %}, it goes through but doesn't print anything.

Traceback

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/ajunkkil/Django/basedraft/messages/views.py" in compose
  91.     }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render_to_response
  20.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  188.         return t.render(context_instance)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  123.             return self._render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  117.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  127.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  117.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  127.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  117.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  64.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  64.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/home/ajunkkil/Django/basedraft/messages/templatetags/getusers.py" in render
  19.         context[self.varname] = User.objects.all()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/context.py" in __setitem__
  53.         self.dicts[-1][key] = value

Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /messages/compose/
Exception Value: Caught TypeError while rendering: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Does it have to be in all templates or just in one?

Comment: Just in one, Its a template for composing a new message and I would like to have the userlist there with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the latest development version, there's a new tag shortcut, [assignment tags](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags), which does all this for you. Then you could just do:

```
@register.assignment_tag
def get_all_users():
    return User.objects.all()
```

The actual problem with your code though is that you're passing the whole list of arguments to the tag instantiation:

```
return GetAllUsers(bits)
```

when you should just be passing the bit that contains the variable name:

```
return GetAllUsers(bits[2])
```

Finally, however, if this is just for one template, I don't understand why you're not doing it in the view, as programmersbook recommends.

Comment: I guess because you recommended to use a tag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867451/django-passing-list-of-objects-to-template ;-)

Comment: Well Daniel, you recommended this way to me. Hehe! as I asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867451/django-passing-list-of-objects-to-template . I have django 1.3 so. I really appreciate your help though.

Comment: Well Daniel your return GetAllUsers(bits[2]) did it. You are awesome! Thank you so much!

Comment: Note the link to the assignment tags is no longer working, since you linked to the dev version and assignment tags have been deprecated. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an [`inclusion tag`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags)?

From what i understand it seems to sit between a [`simple tag`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-template-tags/#shortcut-for-simple-tags) and the `assignment tag` Daniel mentioned. That means
the data isn't output directly as simple tags do. And where an `assignment tag` stores the data in variable which you directly iterate the inclusion tags needs a template snippet for rendering the data.

```
@register.inclusion_tag('users.html')
def show_users():
    users = user.objects.all()
    return {'users': users}
```

Then you can write a template snippet (`users.html`) that exactly renders your user list part.

Answer (score 0):

When maybe is better to do it over the context, don't see a point to use a tag

view:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts               import render_to_response

def users(request):
    user_list = User.objects.all()

    ctx = {'user_list':user_list}

    render_to_response('temp.html', ctx)
```

in template:

```
{% for user in user_list %}
    {{ user }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867451/django-passing-list-of-objects-to-template . This is what I'm originally trying to do, I couldn't figure out how to get my user objects to the "compose" url and list them there. so when I have a url url(r'^compose/$', compose, name='messages_compose'), can I use render_to_response to get the user objects in there?

Comment: If I understood you right, when sure, render_to_response will load and parse the template and return a valid HttpResponse object